# SQL server creating a view with a guid and select distinct clause

Tags: c#, sql-server, select, guid

I have a view in an SQL Server Database that I am trying to use in a C# application, the model requires a Key field which the view does not have.  To get past this I was going to create a guid when creating the view however this causes each row to be different and therefor negates the SELECT DISTINCT clause in the create view.

How would I go about either creating the GUID after the SELECT query so as to only give the results a guid?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Thanks for all the help and comments so far I've managed a workaround but its not pretty and since I'm working on getting better with SQL I'm sure there's a better solution I have one view

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_OpenTradesMarket]
AS

SELECT DISTINCT    TOP (1000)

cast(C.[Link Ref#] AS varchar(max)) as [LinkRef]
,cast(C.[OpenMktBASE] AS varchar(max)) as [Value]
FROM Client AS C

inner JOIN  stgMKTBOTH AS M ON C.[Link Ref#] = M.[Link Ref#]
```

Then I create a view of this table with a row_numberer() to create the numbered table

```
CREATE VIEW vw_OpenTradesTest2
AS 
SELECT 
*
, Row_number() over ( Order by LinkRef) as [Id]
From dbo.vw_OpenTradesMarket
```

Like I say, it works but its not pretty, can you guys improve on this?

Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe instead of a guid you could use row_number? Would return a LOT less data that way. You can put that into a cte in your view and then select where RowNum = 1.

Comment: do you need the key generated to be the same each time for the same row?

Comment: So if I had SELECT DISTINCT Firstname, Surname FROM Table change that to SELECT NEWID(), Firstname, Surname FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Firstname, Surname FROM Table) ?

Comment: May be you can do this in C# - with EF, say using LINQ ?

Comment: The problem using a guid is they are really wide. You are returning 16 bytes for every row instead of 4 if you use an int.

Comment: It doesn't really matter how its done, I really just need each row to have a unique key otherwise the C# just repeats the first record for each record that has the [Key] value in C#, using row_number() creates the same issue as a guid in that it essentially makes each row unique and negates the DISTINCT clause.  In C# in the model I tried public Guid Guid = new Guid(); but the entity framework didn't like it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you could do this. No idea what your tables are like so I created dummy ones.

```
create table Something
(
    SomeVal varchar(10)
)
insert Something
select 'asdf' union all 
select 'asdf' union all 
select 'qwer' union all 
select 'qwer'

go

create view MyView as
    select SomeVal, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by SomeVal) as RowNum
    from Something
    group by SomeVal

go

select *
from MyView

go

drop view MyView
drop table Something
```